# IQueryable<T>.Where() doesn't create proper SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have this simple code:

```csharp
public class AirportRepository : Repository<Airport>
{
    public IQueryable<Airport> GetByCountry(Entity country)
    {
        IQueryable<Airport> airports = GetAll().Where( a => a.CountryId.Equals(country.Id) );

        return airports;
    }
}
```

...which I *thought* would create the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Airport WHERE CountryID = ?
```

...but it creates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Airport
```

...and then do the Where() part on the client side, which is very costly in my case.

What is going on?

**UPDATE:** Here's what the base Repository class look like:

```csharp
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new()
{
    protected SimpleSQLManager SQLManager = DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLManager;

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> all = SQLManager.Table<T>().AsQueryable();

        return all;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #2:** I can't share the code "behind" SQLManager, but after digging through its code, I can see that Table is an IEnumerable. Is that the problem?

**UPDATE #3:** Here's th relevant (I hope) SQLManager code:

```csharp
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a queryable interface to the table represented by the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A queryable object that is able to translate Where, OrderBy, and Take
    /// queries into native SQL.
    /// </returns>  
    public TableQuery<T> Table<T>() where T : new()
    {
        Initialize(false);

        return _db.Table<T>();
    }

public class TableQuery<T> : IEnumerable<T> where T : new()
{
    public SQLiteConnection Connection { get; private set; }

    public TableMapping Table { get; private set; }

    Expression _where;
    List<Ordering> _orderBys;
    int? _limit;
    int? _offset;

    class Ordering
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        public bool Ascending { get; set; }
    }

    TableQuery (SQLiteConnection conn, TableMapping table)
    {
        Connection = conn;
        Table = table;
    }

    public TableQuery (SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        Connection = conn;
        Table = Connection.GetMapping (typeof(T));
    }

    public TableQuery<T> Clone ()
    {
        var q = new TableQuery<T> (Connection, Table);
        q._where = _where;
        if (_orderBys != null) {
            q._orderBys = new List<Ordering> (_orderBys);
        }
        q._limit = _limit;
        q._offset = _offset;
        return q;
    }

    public TableQuery<T> Where (Expression<Func<T, bool>> predExpr)
    {
        if (predExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda) {
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)predExpr;
            var pred = lambda.Body;
            var q = Clone ();
            q.AddWhere (pred);
            return q;
        } else {
            throw new NotSupportedException ("Must be a predicate");
        }
    }

    public TableQuery<T> Take (int n)
    {
        var q = Clone ();
        q._limit = n;
        return q;
    }

    public TableQuery<T> Skip (int n)
    {
        var q = Clone ();
        q._offset = n;
        return q;
    }

    public TableQuery<T> OrderBy<U> (Expression<Func<T, U>> orderExpr)
    {
        return AddOrderBy<U> (orderExpr, true);
    }

    public TableQuery<T> OrderByDescending<U> (Expression<Func<T, U>> orderExpr)
    {
        return AddOrderBy<U> (orderExpr, false);
    }

    protected TableQuery<T> AddOrderBy<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> orderExpr, bool asc)
    {
        if (orderExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda) {
            var lambda = (LambdaExpression)orderExpr;
            var mem = lambda.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (mem != null && (mem.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)) {
                var q = Clone ();
                if (q._orderBys == null) {
                    q._orderBys = new List<Ordering> ();
                }
                q._orderBys.Add (new Ordering {
                    ColumnName = mem.Member.Name,
                    Ascending = asc
                });
                return q;
            } else {
                throw new NotSupportedException ("Order By does not support: " + orderExpr);
            }
        } else {
            throw new NotSupportedException ("Must be a predicate");
        }
    }

    protected void AddWhere(Expression pred)
    {
        if (_where == null) {
            _where = pred;
        } else {
            _where = Expression.AndAlso (_where, pred);
        }
    }

    protected SQLiteCommand GenerateCommand(string selectionList)
    {
        var cmdText = "select " + selectionList + " from \"" + Table.TableName + "\"";
        var args = new List<object> ();
        if (_where != null) {
            var w = CompileExpr (_where, args);
            cmdText += " where " + w.CommandText;
        }
        if ((_orderBys != null) && (_orderBys.Count > 0)) {
            var t = string.Join (", ", _orderBys.Select (o => "\"" + o.ColumnName + "\"" + (o.Ascending ? "" : " desc")).ToArray ());
            cmdText += " order by " + t;
        }
        if (_limit.HasValue) {
            cmdText += " limit " + _limit.Value;
        }
        if (_offset.HasValue) {
            if (!_limit.HasValue) {
                cmdText += " limit -1 ";
            }
            cmdText += " offset " + _offset.Value;
        }
        return Connection.CreateCommand (cmdText, args.ToArray ());
    }

    protected class CompileResult
    {
        public string CommandText { get; set; }

        public object Value { get; set; }
    }

    protected CompileResult CompileExpr(Expression expr, List<object> queryArgs)
    {
        if (expr == null) {
            throw new NotSupportedException ("Expression is NULL");
        } else if (expr is BinaryExpression) {
            var bin = (BinaryExpression)expr;

            var leftr = CompileExpr (bin.Left, queryArgs);
            var rightr = CompileExpr (bin.Right, queryArgs);

            //If either side is a parameter and is null, then handle the other side specially (for "is null"/"is not null")
            string text;
            if (leftr.CommandText == "?" && leftr.Value == null)
                text = CompileNullBinaryExpression(bin, rightr);
            else if (rightr.CommandText == "?" && rightr.Value == null)
                text = CompileNullBinaryExpression(bin, leftr);
            else
                text = "(" + leftr.CommandText + " " + GetSqlName(bin) + " " + rightr.CommandText + ")";
            return new CompileResult { CommandText = text };
        } else if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call) {

            var call = (MethodCallExpression)expr;
            var args = new CompileResult[call.Arguments.Count];

            for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++) {
                args [i] = CompileExpr (call.Arguments [i], queryArgs);
            }

            var sqlCall = "";

            if (call.Method.Name == "Like" && args.Length == 2) {
                sqlCall = "(" + args [0].CommandText + " like " + args [1].CommandText + ")";
            } else if (call.Method.Name == "Contains" && args.Length == 2) {
                sqlCall = "(" + args [1].CommandText + " in " + args [0].CommandText + ")";
            } else {
                sqlCall = call.Method.Name.ToLower () + "(" + string.Join (",", args.Select (a => a.CommandText).ToArray ()) + ")";
            }
            return new CompileResult { CommandText = sqlCall };

        } else if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) {
            var c = (ConstantExpression)expr;
            queryArgs.Add (c.Value);
            return new CompileResult {
                CommandText = "?",
                Value = c.Value
            };
        } else if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) {
            var u = (UnaryExpression)expr;
            var ty = u.Type;
            var valr = CompileExpr (u.Operand, queryArgs);
            return new CompileResult {
                CommandText = valr.CommandText,
                Value = valr.Value != null ? Convert.ChangeType (valr.Value, ty) : null
            };
        } else if (expr.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess) {
            var mem = (MemberExpression)expr;

            if (mem.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter) {
                //
                // This is a column of our table, output just the column name
                //
                return new CompileResult { CommandText = "\"" + mem.Member.Name + "\"" };
            } else {
                object obj = null;
                if (mem.Expression != null) {
                    var r = CompileExpr (mem.Expression, queryArgs);
                    if (r.Value == null) {
                        throw new NotSupportedException ("Member access failed to compile expression");
                    }
                    if (r.CommandText == "?") {
                        queryArgs.RemoveAt (queryArgs.Count - 1);
                    }
                    obj = r.Value;
                }

                //
                // Get the member value
                //
                object val = null;

                if (mem.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) {
                    var m = (PropertyInfo)mem.Member;
                    val = m.GetValue (obj, null);                       
                } else if (mem.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field) {
                    var m = (FieldInfo)mem.Member;
                    val = m.GetValue (obj);                     
                } else {
                    throw new NotSupportedException ("MemberExpr: " + mem.Member.MemberType.ToString ());
                }

                //
                // Work special magic for enumerables
                //
                if (val != null && val is System.Collections.IEnumerable && !(val is string)) {
                    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("(");
                    var head = "";
                    foreach (var a in (System.Collections.IEnumerable)val) {
                        queryArgs.Add(a);
                        sb.Append(head);
                        sb.Append("?");
                        head = ",";
                    }
                    sb.Append(")");
                    return new CompileResult {
                        CommandText = sb.ToString(),
                        Value = val
                    };
                }
                else {
                    queryArgs.Add (val);
                    return new CompileResult {
                        CommandText = "?",
                        Value = val
                    };
                }
            }
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException ("Cannot compile: " + expr.NodeType.ToString ());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compiles a BinaryExpression where one of the parameters is null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter">The non-null parameter</param>
    protected string CompileNullBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression, CompileResult parameter)
    {
        if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
            return "(" + parameter.CommandText + " is ?)";
        else if (expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.NotEqual)
            return "(" + parameter.CommandText + " is not ?)";
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException("Cannot compile Null-BinaryExpression with type " + expression.NodeType.ToString());
    }

    string GetSqlName (Expression expr)
    {
        var n = expr.NodeType;
        if (n == ExpressionType.GreaterThan)
            return ">"; else if (n == ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual) {
            return ">=";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.LessThan) {
            return "<";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual) {
            return "<=";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.And) {
            return "and";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.AndAlso) {
            return "and";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.Or) {
            return "or";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.OrElse) {
            return "or";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.Equal) {
            return "=";
        } else if (n == ExpressionType.NotEqual) {
            return "!=";
        } else {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException ("Cannot get SQL for: " + n.ToString ());
        }
    }

    public int Count ()
    {
        return GenerateCommand("count(*)").ExecuteScalar<int> ();           
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return GenerateCommand ("*").ExecuteQuery<T> ().GetEnumerator ();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator ()
    {
        return GetEnumerator ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Highly improbable.... What is the signature of `GetAll()`? Is it `IQueryable<Airport> GetAll()`?

Comment: The SQL query is already executed inside `GetAll()`. Does that method contain a `ToList()` or `AsEnumerable()` call?

Comment: I do hope there isn't any `AsQueryable()` inside the `GetAll()`...

Comment: What does GetAll() return?

Comment: I've updated the original post with the base Repository class.

Comment: @toreau Now you can continue with showing us `SQLManager.Table<T>()`... The `AsQueryable()` is often a bad news...

Comment: What is `SimpleSQLManager`? How do you obtain the SQL that this code should "create"? `IQueryable<T>` doesn't generate SQL, it's an ORM that leverages `IQueryable<T>` that does so. The issue must be within `SimpleSQLManager`.

Comment: SimpleSQLManager.Table<T> is an IEnumerable. I guess that's the problem?

Comment: @toreau not necessarily. IEnumerable is a root interface, any collection implements that. It will not affect querying

Comment: With all those already given good answers, I would just add a small note. Have you tried using IQToolkit from codeplex? It has support for SQLite and working pretty well.

Comment: IQToolkit looks interesting. I'll have a look at it over the weekend. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You asked why it is creating "wrong" SQL. Let's go step by step.

LINQ is very powerful but sometimes can mislead developers.

`.Where(a => a.CountryId.Equals(country.Id))` is valid and working syntax to filter airports by country (can I suggest to rewrite `a.CountryId == country.id`? Better readability).

Now you can't see what happens in the backstage of LINQ, because it all depends on the actual object you are calling `Where` on. As pointed out by others, call to `AsQueryable` in your `GetAll()` is the cause.

`GetAll()` executes the SQL query, without filtering, so that it will return all `Airport`s, and then the result set is filtered in memory.

Worse, your `SQLManager` seems to be a rough implementation of an ORM. You must discuss with your software architect about implementing `Entity Framework` or `NHibernate` (but I wouldn't recommend the second anymore) that are proper ORMs supporting LINQ. With them, you will find that the queries will be filtered correctly.

Comment: `LINQ to Entities` **is** `Entity Framework`. And its the absence to keep the table as an `IQueryable<T>` that makes it loose the query criteria `.Where(...)`, it is not the adding of an extra `.AsQueryable()` that looses it.

Comment: Thanks for a very informative and precise answer. I'll look into other (better) ORM solutions, then.

Comment: @Maarten wasn't `Linq to Entities` **also** `NHibernate`?

Comment: @Maarten of course he meant "LINQ to SQL", which is a more low-level ORM built in to the .NET Framework.

Comment: @djechelon *GetAll() executes the SQL query, without filtering* Practically correct, technically wrong. We don't know exactly how `GetAll()`/`SQLManager.Table<T>()` are written... They could be written in a way that the query is executed only on enumeration of the `IEnumerable<>` it returns (it would be the easiest way to write it). Clearly if it internally does a `ToList()`/`ToArray()` then the query is executed inside the `GetAll()`, but if it does something like `return somecontext.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x)`, then the query isn't executed inside the `GetAll()`/`SQLManager.Table<T>()`.

Comment: @djechelon The point being (something not always clear for everyone), returning `IEnumerable<>` instead of `IQueryable<>` doesn't implicitly/automatically mean the query has already been executed. It only means that you can't add other query operators that will be executed by the "remote" SQL server (or by whatever engine runs the `IQueryable<>` query)

Comment: @xanatos yes, I came to the conclusion that GetAll() runs the query by its effects, and not by looking at its implementation

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to create another GetAll() method which takes a predicate, and then use that method for the different GetBySomething() methods;

```csharp
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new()
{
    protected SimpleSQLManager SQLManager = DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLManager;

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> all = SQLManager.Table<T>().AsQueryable();

        return all;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> all = SQLManager.Table<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();

        return all;
    }
}

public class AirportRepository : Repository<Airport>
{
    public IQueryable<Airport> GetByCountry(Entity country)
    {
        IQueryable<Airport> airports = GetAll( a => a.CountryId == country.Id );

        return airports;
    }
}
```

This works, but I assume it's not very pretty?