# Repository pattern and combined/joined entities as optimised SQL

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I'm working on building a repository system on top of a system that is a bit harder to work on than usual (ref. a [previous question by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608960/iqueryablet-where-doesnt-create-proper-sql)).

Anyway.

My data model is fairly simple at this point: I have several countries, and each country has 0 or more airports. Here's my base Repository:

```csharp
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : Entity, new()
{
    protected SimpleSQLManager SQLManager = DatabaseManager.Instance.SQLManager;

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> all = SQLManager.Table<T>().AsQueryable();

        return all;
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<T> all = SQLManager.Table<T>().Where(predicate).AsQueryable();

        return all;
    }

    public T GetById(string tableName, int id)
    {
        return SQLManager.Query<T>( "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE Id = ?", id )[0];
    }
}
```

Please ignore the ugly `GetById()` implementation; I'm running this on Unity3D's (Mono's) .NET libraries, and there's seemingly [a bug](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/system-dot-argumentexception-the-field-handle-and-the-type-handle-are-incompatible) in there which makes it impossible at the moment to do it properly. Either way, that's not the problem. :)

Now, a normal EntityRepository looks like this (CountryRepository in this case):

```csharp
public class CountryRepository : Repository<Country>
{
    public override IQueryable<Country> GetAll()
    {
        return base.GetAll().OrderBy( c => c.Name );
    }

    public Country GetById(int id)
    {
        return base.GetById( "Country", id );
    }
}
```

The Country entity looks like this:

```csharp
public class Country : Entity
{
    public IQueryable<Airport> Airports()
    {
        return RepositoryFactory.AirportRepository.GetByCountry( this );
    }
}
```

Then, in my application I can do something like this:

```csharp
foreach ( Country c in RepositoryFactory.CountryRepository.GetAll() )
{
    foreach ( Airport a in c.Airports() )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

...and this works just fine; I'm happy with how everything is abstracted away etc. etc. :)

**The problem** is that the above code creates one database SELECT per country, which is highly ineffective. This is where I'm not sure where to go forward. I *know* how to do this with plain old SQL, but I want to go the Linq (or otherwise "non-SQL") way.

Can someone point me in the right/correct direction?

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions. Why would you need to aggregate airports within countries? What command processing use case requires a country and all it's airports to be processed? Domain models shouldn't be crafted to satisfy query needs, only commands.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I understand what you mean? Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see anything in SimpleSQL's documentation that looked like it would make sql lite generate a join--something like entity framework's `Include` method.

That said, you could just bring in all airports and countries into memory with 2 queries and hook them to each other manually, like so:

```
var airports = RepositoryFactory.AirportRepository.GetAll().ToList();
var countries = RepositoryFactory.CountryRepository.GetAll().ToList();
countries.ForEach(c => c.Airports = airports.Where(a => a.CountryId == c.Id));
```

Note that you'll need to add a property to your country class:

```
public IEnumerable<Airport> Airports {get;set;}
```

I don't like it, but that might be the only way given your environment. You could further abstract the join/mapping logic with generics, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: This works, and is a lot faster, but I also don't like it. I think I'll stick with it for the time being, though, unless someone else comes up with something even better.

Comment: Good deal. I hope someone with more experience using sql lite has a cleaner solution. Maybe there's a better sql lite ORM out there that will have more features.